# How does my Epson printer automatically install its software when it connects to my network?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, printer

I bought an [Epson XP-410](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?sku=C11CC87201) printer earlier this week. I connected it to my Wi-Fi network and got it set up. I tested it by printing to it after installing the drivers that came on a DVD to a computer on the same network as the printer.

A few days later, I go to another computer—same network as the earlier computer and printer—and notice that this software is already installed, with absolutely no intervention from me:

[image]

Additionally, I could print to it, though I had to set it as my default printer.

I checked all other computers on my network—3 of them, along with 5 Android devices—and all computers had this installed; nothing on the phones. I have two questions:

1. How did a printer automatically add itself to my computer and install software
2. What’s to stop someone maliciously bringing in, say, a cell phone, connecting it to my home network and installing software to my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Update recognized it automatically and installed the drivers and software for you. The same program was installed when I connected a non-wireless Epson printer to a Windows 10 Tech Preview laptop.

Comment: Are you saying Windows Update works on WiFi devices just like it does on USB devices?

Comment: Why would it be different? It gets some sort of ID from the printer associated with its specific model and attempts to make it work for users, so they don't have to do it themselves (and take the risk of installing the wrong driver/program).